# Input text with css "width 100%" larger than container

Tags: html, css, html-input

If a `select` tag respects the 100% defined in the CSS, then why can't an `input`? When inspecting it at the `Box Model` in Firefox, I see a padding of 1 and a lateral border of 5.33333!

[image: screenshot showing border > 5]

Why doesn't that border appear around the input? And why is it defined so large as default? What for? I noticed that applying a CSS `box-sizing:border-box;` solves the issue, but where is all this specified? I see nothing on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text).

```css
div {
  background-color:green;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
#txt {
  width:100%;
}
#sel {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <input type='text' id='txt' />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <select id='sel'>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it's the default style add to the input (adding duplicate for it too)

Comment: added more duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, but I just couldn't find where 5.33333 is coming from. I looked in forms.css and in html.css (resource://gre-resources/).

Comment: you will have headaches trying to find this, you simply need to know that each browser add a default style that you can see on inspecting the element. You should never rely on default styles that's why in most of sites you see a reset.css to remove those default one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see. I would just like to understand why 5.33333 for something that obviously is occupying ~ 1 pixel. Because *maybe* understanding how this people think could make CSS more intuitive...

Comment: can you add a screenshot of where you see the 5.333 .. on my side I only see 2px padding and 1px border

Comment: @TemaniAfif Edited the question to add the picture. I'm using Firefox Quantum 68.0.1 (64-bit, with 150% zoom) on Debian 9.